# Transposing Rows in to colums in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have an sql query "Select * from tablename" whose output is

```
col1   col2       
  A     1 
  B     2 
  C     3
```

I want to modify the above output to below as following

```
A      B      C
1      2      3
```

Please let me know how could I achieve this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get ROWS as COLUMNS (SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074939/get-rows-as-columns-sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to perform a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  There are two ways to do this with PIVOT, either a Static Pivot where you code the columns to transform or a Dynamic Pivot which determines the columns at execution.

Static Pivot:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM yourTable
) x
PIVOT
(
   min(col2)
   for col1 in ([A], [B], [C])
)p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39ec3/1)

Dynamic Pivot:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(col1) 
                    from t1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select col1, col2
                from t1
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(col2)
                for col1 in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39ec3/2)

If you do not want to use the `PIVOT` function, then you can perform a similar type of query with `CASE` statements:

```
select 
  SUM(CASE WHEN col1 = 'A' THEN col2 END) as A,
  SUM(CASE WHEN col1 = 'B' THEN col2 END) as B,
  SUM(CASE WHEN col1 = 'C' THEN col2 END) as C
FROM t1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39ec3/12)

Comment: thanks for the above solution but for Dynamic Pivot the order of the column is changed i.e. the column name comes in desc order where as i don't want to change the order of column...is there any way to keep the order of column as it is..as this code select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(col1)                      from t1             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')          ,1,1,'')  changes the column order

Comment: @user1418827 instead of using `DISTINCT` on that query, you can use a `GROUP BY col1 ORDER BY col1` and that should get them in order.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `PIVOT` or  `COALESCE` in sql.Here is  a nice examples how to converting rows to columns.
 [Five methods converting rows to columns](http://sqlserveradvisor.blogspot.com/2009/03/sql-server-convert-rows-to-columns.html)

.