# Rows to columns SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am writing a query that will be used in a .NET application, therefore I would like the SQL Server 2008 o do much of the processing for me instead of the client PC that the application will run on.

I am trying to get data from some tables I joined together.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(HCPD.SeferCikisZamani AS TIME) AS VARCHAR), 1, 5) AS Kalkis, SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(HCPD.DonusZamani AS TIME) AS VARCHAR), 1, 5) AS Donus, V.AracPlaka
FROM HAT_CALISMA_PLANI HCP WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN HAT_CALISMA_PLANI_DETAY HCPD WITH(NOLOCK) ON HCPD.HatCalismaPlaniKey = HCP.HatCalismaPlaniKey
INNER JOIN VALIDATOR V WITH(NOLOCK) ON V.ValidatorKey = HCPD.ValidatorKey
WHERE HCP.HatKey = 2 AND CAST(HCPD.SeferCikisZamani AS DATE) = '2012-09-25'
ORDER BY Kalkis
```

This query returns this result:

```
Kalkis  Donus   AracPlaka
-------------------------
01:51   02:01   07 ABY 04
02:02   02:12   07 AB 978
02:21   02:31   07 ABY 04
02:32   02:42   07 AB 978
03:01   03:11   07 ABY 04
03:02   03:12   07 AB 978
03:31   03:41   07 ABY 04
03:42   03:52   07 AB 978
04:01   04:11   07 ABY 04
```

However, In my report they are supposed to look like this,

```
        07 ABY 04   07 AB 978
Kalkis  06:15       06:30
Donus   07:45       08:00
Kalkis  08:00       08:10
Donus   09:30       09:40
Kalkis  10:00       10:15
Donus   11:30       11:45
Kalkis  12:30       12:45
Donus   14:00       14:15
```

By the way, these are like bus schedules.
Anyone know a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Using pivot function and get your result. Use this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: What is the relations between the times in the pivoted table and the times in the original one? for example in the first row `Kalkis  06:15       06:30` where does `06:15` and `06:3` come from??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easier to see the data before you queried it, but if you want to use your existing query, you can do the following:

```
select *
from
(
  select AracPlaka, val, col,
     row_number() over(partition by AracPlaka order by VAL, col) rn
  from
  (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(HCPD.SeferCikisZamani AS TIME) AS VARCHAR), 1, 5) AS Kalkis, 
      SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(HCPD.DonusZamani AS TIME) AS VARCHAR), 1, 5) AS Donus, 
      V.AracPlaka
    FROM HAT_CALISMA_PLANI HCP WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN HAT_CALISMA_PLANI_DETAY HCPD WITH(NOLOCK) 
      ON HCPD.HatCalismaPlaniKey = HCP.HatCalismaPlaniKey
    INNER JOIN VALIDATOR V WITH(NOLOCK) 
      ON V.ValidatorKey = HCPD.ValidatorKey
    WHERE HCP.HatKey = 2 
      AND CAST(HCPD.SeferCikisZamani AS DATE) = '2012-09-25'
   -- ORDER BY Kalkis
  ) x
  unpivot
  (
    val
    for col in(Kalkis, Donus)
  ) u
) x1
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for AracPlaka In([07 ABY 04], [07 AB 978])
) p
```

Since you are attempting to `PIVOT` two columns, the easiest way is to `UNPIVOT` the `Kalkis` and the `Donus` columns first, then apply the `PIVOT` to the data.

Here is a [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d5f0/42) (excludes your original query)

Comment: thank you for your brilliant answer. but it only returns one Donus and one Kalkis. It was supposed to go like Donus, Kalkis,  Donus, Kalkis,  Donus, Kalkis...

`col     07 ABY 04     07 AB 978
Donus 04:11       03:52
Kalkis 04:01       03:42`

Comment: @MehmetBudak can you create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with a working data model from each table?  Then I can review the query and try to get it working.

Comment: you are brilliant my friend! you are just brilliant! thank you for your time!

Comment: one last question @bluefeet, how can I fill this part dynamically?

  `max(val)
  for AracPlaka In([07 ABY 04], [07 AB 978])`. This information is in this table VALIDATOR (AracPlaka)

Comment: and also I am able to get appropriate AracPlaka information from this query.

`SELECT V.AracPlaka
    FROM HAT_CALISMA_PLANI HCP WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN HAT_CALISMA_PLANI_DETAY HCPD WITH(NOLOCK) ON HCPD.HatCalismaPlaniKey = HCP.HatCalismaPlaniKey
    INNER JOIN VALIDATOR V WITH(NOLOCK) ON V.ValidatorKey = HCPD.ValidatorKey
    WHERE HCP.HatKey = 2 AND CAST(HCPD.SeferCikisZamani AS DATE) = '2012-09-25'
    GROUP BY V.AracPlaka`

Comment: @MehmetBudak here is a dynamic sample of a `PIVOT` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847584/transposing-rows-in-to-colums-in-sql-server-2005/11847747#11847747