# Using a parameter in a pivot in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have this SQL in SSRS:

```
Select * From
(
   Select TermCode, SubjectCode, Course, QuestionNbr, Answer, Question_Format, Question_Text, Tally
   From View_Responses_CourseLvl
   Where Form_Category = 'SIRS' and TermCode = @Term and SubjectCode = 'ANR' and cast(left(Course, 3) as int) = 250 and Question_Format = 'Radio-Option') t

Pivot (sum(Tally) for Answer in (@AnswerParms)) as pvt
```

The problem is, when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near @AnswerParms
```

I really can't see where the problem is or how to go about fixing it.  What am I not seeing?

Comment: You can't use a parameter like that with the column names - you will need to use dynamic SQL see this question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847584/transposing-rows-in-to-colums-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: I did the dynamic SQL and while it works in the Management Studio, it doesn't seem to in SSRS.  I'll try it again.

Answer (score 0):

The SSRS Report Designer cannot work with a dynamic set columns returned by a dataset.

I would remove the SQL Pivot and outer SELECT, and use the SSRS Column Groups feature to group into columns by "Answer".