# Am I using PIVOT correctly?

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Id     Client     Sessions
--------------------------
1      A          34
1      B          23
2      A          20
3      A          45
3      B          20
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
Id     ClientA    ClientB
-------------------------
1      34         23
2      20         0
3      45         20
```

I think this is a case where I am supposed to use `PIVOT`, but I am not sure how to write the query. Is this on the right track?

```
SELECT b.Id, 'A' ClientA, 'B' ClientB
FROM
(SELECT a.Id, a.Client, a.Sessions
FROM Table1 a) b
PIVOT
(b.Sessions FOR b.Id in (SELECT b.Id FROM b))
```

Comment: You cannot use `FOR b.Id in (SELECT b.Id FROM b)` in your pivot like that.  You have to hard-code the values like this `FOR Client in (A, B)` or your need to use dynamic sql if you are going to have unknown values.  You also have a few other syntax issues including missing an aggregate function around `Sessions` take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847584/transposing-rows-in-to-colums-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select Id,
       [A] as 'ClientA',
       [B] as 'ClientB',
from Table1
pivot
( max(Sessions) for Client in ([A], [B]) ) as pvt
order by Id
```

You need an aggregate function around Sessions. Try using max, avg as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have the solution for your problem, use this script :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE Temp

SELECT 
    *
INTO Temp
FROM(
SELECT 1 AS Id, 'A' AS Client, 34 AS [Sessions] UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS Id, 'B' AS Client, 23 AS [Sessions] UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS Id, 'A' AS Client, 20 AS [Sessions] UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS Id, 'A' AS Client, 45 AS [Sessions] UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS Id, 'B' AS Client, 20 AS [Sessions]
) AS T

DECLARE @Col NVARCHAR(4000) = '';

WITH A AS (SELECT DISTINCT LTRIM(RTRIM(Client)) AS Client FROM Temp)
SELECT @Col =  @Col+',['+'Client'+Client+']'
FROM A

SET @Col = RIGHT(@Col, LEN(@Col)-1)

select @Col





EXEC('SELECT
                 Id
                ,'+@Col+'
        FROM
            (SELECT Id, ''Client''+LTRIM(RTRIM(Client)) [Client], [Sessions]
         FROM Temp) AS TT
    PIVOT (MAX([Sessions])
        FOR Client in('+@Col+')) as pvt')
```

I hope it will help you,
Good Luck :)